# How to print 2d array of objects in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2d array of objects, where I've assigned each index an object:

```
for row in range(0, 9):
        for column in range(0, 9):
            self.Matrix[row][column] = Square(row, column)
```

where Square() is an object that takes in a specific index. Each Square object has a method constructor (`def __str__`) that will print a specific text(ex. "KN") for its specific coordinates. I've tried just printing the matrix:

```
print self.Matrix()
```

but I end up getting a really long that's something like

```
[[<__main__.Square object at 0x101936d90>, <__main__.Square object at 0x101936dd0>, <__main__.Square object at 0x101936e10>, .....
```

How can I print the actual objects instead?

Comment: Are you sure you had the parentheses in the `print`, after `Matrix`?  Because I think you should have gotten an error if you did.

Comment: You are printing as repr instead of str. How self.Matrix() is implemented?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you're printing the `Matrix` that contains the `Square`s. This calls the `__str__()` *for the `Matrix` class*. If you haven't defined a `__str__()` for that class that returns a string comprising *the `str()` of each of its contained objects*, it'll give you the `repr()` of each of those objects, as defined by their `__repr__()`. I don't suppose you've defined one. The default is a mere memory location, as you see.

Here's a demo with a stub class:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __str__(self):
...             return 'a'
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return 'b'
...
>>> print(A())
a
>>> A()
b
>>> [A(), A()]
[b, b]
>>> print([A(), A()])
[b, b]
>>> print(*[A(), A()])
a a
```

The solution is to either define a specific `__str__()` for `Matrix` that returns the `str()` for each of its contained objects, or define a suitable `__repr__()` for the `Square` objects (which should be something that could be passed to `eval()` to recreate the object, not just something like "KN").

Answer (score 1):

You should use __repr__

[difference between __repr__ and __str__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

```
class A():
    def __str__(self):
        return "this is __str__"

class B():
    def __repr__(self):
        return "this is __repr__"

a = [A() for one in range(10)]
b = [B() for one in range(10)]

print a
[<__main__.A instance at 0x103e314d0>, <__main__.A instance at 0x103e31488>]
print b
[this is __repr__, this is __repr__]
```